# How to use Argon2 with salt from binary file?

Tags: linux, passwords, hashing

In the Linux program `Argon2`, we need to supply the salt in the command line. This limits the salt to be printable characters. How can we use a binary string as the salt?

```
# argon2 -h

Usage:  argon2 [-h] salt [-i|-d|-id] [-t iterations] [-m log2(memory in KiB) | -k memory in KiB] [-p parallelism] [-l hash length] [-e|-r] [-v (10|13)]
        Password is read from stdin
Parameters:
        salt            The salt to use, at least 8 characters
        -i              Use Argon2i (this is the default)
        -d              Use Argon2d instead of Argon2i
        -id             Use Argon2id instead of Argon2i
        -t N            Sets the number of iterations to N (default = 3)
        -m N            Sets the memory usage of 2^N KiB (default 12)
        -k N            Sets the memory usage of N KiB (default 4096)
        -p N            Sets parallelism to N threads (default 1)
        -l N            Sets hash output length to N bytes (default 32)
        -e              Output only encoded hash
        -r              Output only the raw bytes of the hash
        -v (10|13)      Argon2 version (defaults to the most recent version, currently 13)
        -h              Print argon2 usage
```

I tried using `\x0A` notation does not work. As see below, `\x0A` and `\x0a` produce different hashes.

```
# cat /tmp/keyfile | argon2 "\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x1A\x1B\x1C\x1D" -id -t 4 -m 5 -p 1 -l 64 -r

6694bba14b3955a77beea3fb4c6018bd86953627949df2bc7e57bc7597519d2fed64a24380757bf6d963115656ce0ddcf59b2504b736036c239101c3e069849b

# cat /tmp/keyfile | argon2 "\x0a\x0B\x0C\x0D\x1A\x1B\x1C\x1D" -id -t 4 -m 5 -p 1 -l 64 -r 

3e97b90537a9ecdceaee638aee2b122c89a2cc3e03630bac31cf72c9b7e3e0565a4c3945eb7fc2a04922bb1453cc5fdafc3303327097749b0ceb87111cd1349c
```

For extra information, I would like to use Argon to simulate LUKS's PBKDF.

Comment: I found a partial solution: `eval 'cat /tmp/keyfile | argon2 '$(printf "\xab\xbc\x1b\x5b\xd9\x19\x2b\xce\x04\x59\x1c\x31\x97\xcc\x03\xd9\x13\x5a\x6f\x54\x6a\x1b\x81\xb8\xc6\x93\x0e\x19\xd1\xa0\x0c\x15")' -id -t 4 -m 5 -p 1 -l 64'`. But if the hex is `` " ' ( )` it will break. So I have to `grep` to check if it contains those hex, by `grep -e ' 60 ' -e ' 27 ' -e ' 22 ' -e ' 28 ' -e ' 29 '`.

Comment: POSIX Shell escape sequences are octal, not hex.

Answer (score 0):

In the feature request
[argon2 executable: Add option -b which allows to provide the salt in base64 encoding #264](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/pull/264),
an
[answer](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/pull/264#issuecomment-657531416)
by the author mentioned a new `-b` parameter that uses the salt in
base64 format.

The sources of argon2 seem indeed to be more recent than the release.

The switch is supposed to be used as:

```
argon2 <base64-encoding> -b
```

You might need to compile argon2 from source to have the latest
version with the `-b` option.
If it still does not work, ask the author, identified as "charno".

Answer (score 0):

I find that just `cat` the file in an inner shell would work.

```
% xxd argon2id.salt 
00000000: abbc 1b5b d919 2bce 0459 1c31 97cc 03d9  ...[..+..Y.1....
00000010: 135a 6f54 6a1b 81b8 c693 0e19 d1a0 0c15  .ZoTj...........

% cat keyfile | argon2 "$(cat argon2id.salt)" -id -t 4 -m 5 -p 1 -l 64
Type:           Argon2id
Iterations:     4
Memory:         32 KiB
Parallelism:    1
Hash:           83ed8343d0539ba4f44fd79ac1becce1c7dd5001b7098f0cfb6a6cc7a07123890ccafb4cf8b7a8cb3ba1475e738f1268fb66eb89c42faf8460272878781cd952
Encoded:        $argon2id$v=19$m=32,t=4,p=1$q7wbW9kZK84EWRwxl8wD2RNab1RqG4G4xpMOGdGgDBU$g+2DQ9BTm6T0T9eawb7M4cfdUAG3CY8M+2psx6BxI4kMyvtM+LeoyzuhR15zjxJo+2bricQvr4RgJyh4eBzZUg
0.000 seconds
Verification ok
```

The special characters will not break this toy too.

```
% xxd another.salt 
00000000: 6027 2228 2960 2722 2829 6027 2228 2960  `'"()`'"()`'"()`
00000010: 2722 2829 6027 2228 2960 2722 2829 6027  '"()`'"()`'"()`'
00000020: 2228 29                              

% cat keyfile| argon2 "$(cat another.salt)" -id -t 4 -m 5 -p 1 -l 64   
Type:           Argon2id
Iterations:     4
Memory:         32 KiB
Parallelism:    1
Hash:           c5de872b35447ad75b3a9581fb1cf85a31ae61d92594b61888e8ca4701c32b13639656f5222cde7e5cb59be0731e0782871315747f542af0941cecfcfecb6027
Encoded:        $argon2id$v=19$m=32,t=4,p=1$YCciKClgJyIoKWAnIigpYCciKClgJyIoKWAnIigpYCciKCk$xd6HKzVEetdbOpWB+xz4WjGuYdkllLYYiOjKRwHDKxNjllb1Iizefly1m+BzHgeChxMVdH9UKvCUHOz8/stgJw
0.000 seconds
Verification ok
```